# Deploying a War File to Tomcat Root With Maven pom.xml

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, web-applications, maven, pom.xml

Assuming the following `pom.xml` maven would build a `client.war` file which when deployed to Tomcat will have the URL `www.server.com:8080/client/`

What would one have to change so the application can be reached at the server root `www.server.com:8080/`?

> ```
> <project>
>     <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
>     <groupId>...</groupId>
>     <artifactId>client</artifactId>
>     <packaging>war</packaging>
>     <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
>     <name>...</name>
>     <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
>     <build>
>         <resources>
>             <resource>
>                 <directory>target/generated-resources</directory>
>             </resource>
>             <resource>
>                 <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
>                 <filtering>true</filtering>
>             </resource>
>         </resources>
>         <plugins>
>             ...
>         </plugins>
>         <finalName>client</finalName>
>     </build>
> ...
> </project>
> ```

Comment: Rename you resulting war file into ROOT.war and remove the one from Tomcat after deploy this should work.

Comment: This created a project that is now reachable under /root/. Can the server.xml or something be modified to point at /client/ as the default page?

Comment: If you call it ROOT.war instead of root.war it says OK in the manager and deploys it but the result is still ´It works !

If you're seeing this page via a web browser, it means you've setup Tomcat successfully. Congratulations!´

Answer (score 8):

I believe you can leave the war named client.war if you'd like.  Then configure the [tomcat6 plugin](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2/tomcat6-maven-plugin/deploy-mojo.html), setting the path like this:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.0-beta-1</version>
      <!-- put the configuration in an execution if you want to... -->
      <configuration>
        <path>/</path>
        <warFile>${project.build.directory}/client.war</warFile>
        <!-- other config options here -->
      </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I haven't used tomcat7 version of the plugin, but I'm guessing it's similar.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using the combination of eclipse, tomcat, and maven, I'm going to make the guess that the m2e-wtp plugin is in use here. There's a [FAQ that addresses this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E-WTP_FAQ#How_do_I_change_the_context_root_of_my_project.3F). This also shows though how to change your context root in a maven specific way (using the war plugin for specifying a finalName for the war) which results in a correctly named war file (such as ROOT.war as mentioned in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Maven war plugin (which is defined on super-pom by default) will only generate a war file. It's up to you to set up your app on Tomcat. If you want to add the "deploy to a container" to your maven build, go with [Tomcat Maven Plugin](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin.html) or [Cargo Maven Plugin](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin).

What you want has nothing to do with Maven, actually. Setting your war name to ROOT.war should do it (`<finalName>ROOT</finalName>` on your build section), but if you want to add your `context.xml` to the war file, you could do something like (assuming `src/main/webapp` is your webapp folder defined by maven):

```
`<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>

<artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>  
        <configuration>  
          <webResources>  
            <webResource>  
              <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/META-INF</directory>  
              <includes>  
                <include>context.xml</include>  
              </includes>  
              <targetPath>META-INF</targetPath>  
              <filtering>true</filtering>  
            </webResource>  
          </webResources>  
        </configuration>  
      </plugin>
```

`