# Apache tomcat/maven deployment

Tags: maven, tomcat

I am trying so hard to deploy my website without the use of my IDE (Intellij). And I am having some major issues. As soon as I fix one thing I hit another road block and it takes me a few days of getting frustrated and giving up and coming back to it to even get any closer. So I am hoping someone can help me here!

First, I am using Intellij, Tomcat 8, JSF, and Maven. I am first off confused on a few things, the first thing is how tomcat even knows what to deploy. Secondly what on earth is a manager

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <path>/${project.build.finalName}</path>
                <update>true</update>
                <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                <username>tomcat</username>
                <password>tomcatuser</password>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

And third how on earth is the file structure suppose to look like. Because if you are using apache tomcat do all the files also go in the project structure? Or can you leave tomcat separate and just link your tomcat to the correct directory containing your application?

```
<role rolename="tomcat" />
    <role rolename="manager-gui" />
    <role rolename="manager-script" />
    <role rolename="admin-gui" />
    <user username="tomcat" password="tomcatuser"
          roles="tomcat,manager-gui,admin-gui,manager-script" />
```

As of right now I put all of the files that are in apaches folder into my main directory of my project because I was having issues and got tired of trying to fix it. Now I am trying to deploy (Which to be honest I am not sure what the difference between deploy and run is) I am guessing maybe deploy recreates the war file? And run just runs the current war file? Anyways not the point. The run seems to work ok, only problem is I cant stop the service with shutdown. And it also has a context path which I do not want. I want no context path if that is possible.

The next problem is that when I run tomcat7:deploy (in the ide) it gives me this error.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:deploy (default-cli) on project JavaServerFaces: Tomcat return http status error: 404, Reason Phrase: Not Found: -> [Help 1]
```

I think its because there is no /manager/text.... but I dont even know what a manager is at this point so I am kind of lost. Hopefully someone can help me get a better grasp of how everything is structured/done with apache tomcat.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Servlet API](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr315/) each web application has to be packaged in its own "war" file. This is aside of Tomcat. This applies to **any** standard Java web application server.

There are [several ways](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/deployer-howto.html) of deploying applications in Tomcat. Deploying using the Tomcat Manager is [one of them](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/deployer-howto.html#Deploying_using_the_Tomcat_Manager). The Tomcat manager is just another web application with [special permissions](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Introduction), like the required to deploy applications. The manager application is usually distributed among with the [Tomcat binaries](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi).

Tomcat is a server. It lives in its own process and communicates with the world through the port 8080 by default. With the manager installed, it is open for other processes to deploy applications through HTTP requests. The browser or any other user agent.

Your IDE starts a Maven process which uses the official [tomcat7-maven-plugin](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/deploy-mojo.html) to perform such requests. The plugin, in turn, requires the manager application already deployed since it will perform [an HTTP PUT request](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Deploy_A_New_Application_Remotely) with your war file as the body in order to deploy your application. Notice that you could run Maven outside of your IDE, you just need the pom.xml file.

The users and roles file is just the (global) file required by one of the several authentication configurations possible in Tomcat: the [MemoryRealm](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/realm-howto.html#MemoryRealm). Notice that the manager application requires [special roles](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/realm-howto.html#Manager_Application) there.

I think the HTTP 404 error is due to the fact that you  don't have the manager application in the target Tomcat server where the plugin is pointing to. Just follow the steps of the [Manager App HOWTO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/manager-howto.html) in order to propertly configure it.

The difference between run and deploy [goals of the tomcat7-maven-plugin](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html) is that run will embed a server right there, in the same maven process, while the deploy goals is designed to deploy a war file in another, possibly remote, process. I don't know about the shutdown goal not working, maybe you find an answer [in a smiliar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22781039/why-cant-i-shutdown-tomcat-7-embedded-from-maven-plugin).

Follow [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449354/deploying-a-war-file-to-tomcat-root-with-maven-pom-xml) too, in order to deploy an application as the "ROOT" application.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! That answered a lot of questions :P. Ill go through some of these links and follow the way they are doing things and see If i can get this working! I at least now have a understanding and some resources that point me in a good direction! Thanks a lot!