# access tomcat application via the domain name

Tags: dns

I have a virtual cloud server on aws where there is tomcat 7 running on port 8080 eg. a.x.y.z:8080 (where a.x.y.z is the public ip). I have an application deployed on the tomcat on context path "hello" so that I can access it like a.x.y.z:8080/hello .
Now I have bought a domain name example.com and have translated it to the public ip a.x.y.z so that now I can access my application via the url example.com:8080/hello but actually what I want is that on hitting example.com I would be able to access my application. How to achieve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved the issue :

After installing apache2, in the /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file
I appended :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName www.example.com
  ServerAlias example.com
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

Saved the file and restarted the apache2 server.
With this, whenever I hit example.com, I will get the homepage of tomcat (localhost:8080). then i opened the tomcat manager (example.com/manager/html) and stopped & undeployed the application at root (/) path. (As a result of this, whenever you hit example.com, you will no longer see tomcat homepage, instead a blank page)

Now I deployed my application as **root** in tomcat. If you are using maven you can do so like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449354/deploying-a-war-file-to-tomcat-root-with-maven-pom-xml) .
As a result of this my application was available in example.com .
(If you don't deploy your application as root, you have to access it using example.com/myapp)

Now, whenever I hit example.com *myapp* will be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

You can access your tomcat application with your domain name using mod_proxy modules, please login your server and update your httpd configuration with following code.

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:8080/
```

NOTE : Update your correct server IP instead of 0.0.0.0 in above code.